# Object.defineObject, reuse object or object literal notation

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

```
var obj = {};

Object.defineProperty(this, 'foo', void (obj.value = 0) || obj);
Object.defineProperty(this, 'foo2', void (obj.value = 1) || obj);
```

vs.

```
Object.defineProperty(this, 'foo', {value:0});
Object.defineProperty(this, 'foo2', {value:1});
```

Both appear to run just as quickly, but would the former be better for gc?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do...

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: `void whatever || obj` always returns `obj`, as `void whatever` is always undefined.

Comment: It's shorthand. I am interested to know if this will help with gc. (reusing the same object)

Comment: It's the same as:
obj.value = 0;
Object.defineProperty(this, 'foo', obj);

Comment: I don't think this makes any difference for gc.

Comment: A good engine might optimize the "static" object literal that is passed to the native method. With the explicit object reuse this will not be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Option B creates two temporary objects whereas option A creates only one. However the temporary objects in option B are eligable for GC immediately, and could in theory be optimised away more easily than the temporary object in option A, which lives until the end of the block you declare it `var` in.

There will be little to no practical difference in performance; fiddling at this level is premature optimisation (and often it's not possible to choose a fastest version across all browsers anyway). You should go with option B, which is far more readable and idiomatic JavaScript.

FWIW for me (on Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit), testing 100k runs over five tries leads to neither being consistently faster in either Firefox or Chrome (ie random noise is larger than any difference in performance).

Comment: It's not premature optimization (I've already written everything, and I'm now trying to optimize for mobile). The code above is a sudo example, the obj would be stored as a global var, and would be reused throughout the entire code-base for this one purpose. I did a performance test, and the first method is actually faster than the second, but I care more about gc. The gc appears to be causing slowdown on mobile, which is why I'm trying to make optimizations like this. So, assuming I'm using this object over and over, would it be better?

Comment: Keeping one global object with one property around for document lifetime is no strain at all on GC. But making your code less readable to accomodate it is very unlikely to make sense. Difficult to judge in more detail with only pseudo-examples; for this example it is obviously better to do it without `Object.defineProperty` at all, resulting in hundredfold speedup...

Comment: It's generated code. I don't care if it's readable. And yes, not using Object.defineProperty is much faster, I know, but then it's enumerable. I want to know if object literals (like those in the second example) have a significant impact on performance due to gc.

Comment: Significant? In any realistic program I can think of, no. There must be lower hanging fruit than this surely? It's unusual to be `defineProperty`ing a large number of times; normally you would do it once per type, on the prototype.

Comment: Let's say 10,000 times.

Comment: Well, if the first method is faster on mobile then it's faster. What else do you care? Since mobiles are the performance-critical application (probably with a less optimising engine), you should optimize your code for them.